# Regexp for match second numeric values

Tags: c#, sql, regex

Current Strings are

```
   ABC 70 1 MG-MCG Paper
   ABC 70 10 MCG Paper
   ABC 70 150 MG-MCG Paper
   ABC 70 1.50 MG-MCG Paper
   ABC 70 10.50 MG-MCG Paper
   ABC 70 10-50 MG-MCG Paper

   ABC 705 1 MG-MCG Paper
   ABC 705 10 MCG Paper
   ABC 705 150 MG-MCG Paper
   ABC 705 1.50 MG-MCG Paper
   ABC 705 10.50 MG-MCG Paper
   ABC 705 10-50 MG Paper
```

Expected Output :

```
1  
 10  
 150  
 1.50  
 10.50  
 10-50  
 1  
 10  
 150  
 1.50  
 10.50  
 10-50
```

Treid Exp -

```
string c=Regex.Match(result,@"(\d{4}|\d{3}|(..\.\d{1,2}))").Value;
return c
```

How to select second numeric value and Before MG or MCG value

Comment: Since the data seems to be very well ordered, I'd say that a regex looking for numbers is the wrong way to go. Instead, look for whatever is between second and third space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Regex.Match` with the following pattern:

```
(\d+(?:[.-]\d+)?) MG-MCG
```

This matches the number, optionally a decimal or two part number separated by hyphen, which comes immediately before the string `MG-MCG`.

```
string input = " ABC 70 10.1-50.2 MG-MCG Paper";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[.-]\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?) MG-MCG");
if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

### Demo

Comment: its not work for string input = "   ABC 70 10.1-50.2 MG-MCG Paper";

Comment: @John I updated my regex per your new requirements.  By the way, in general you should not change your question like this as you might draw downvotes.

Comment: Thnak you . I missed that condition. There is any tutorial to learn that type of regexp ?

Comment: @John There is one site which I like (http://www.rexegg.com).  Beyond this, participating in regex questions on Stack Overflow is a great way to learn.  I learned much about regex here.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex provides the output you want:

```
var match = Regex.Match(result, @"\d+\s+(\d+(?:[.-]\d+)?)");
if (match.Success)
{
    var num = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: its not work for string input = "   ABC 70 10.1-50.2 MG-MCG Paper";

Answer (score 0):

Other answers went for a regex, but since the data is so well ordered, I'd suggest something else.

I would go for this:

```
string input="ABC 70 10-50 MG-MCG Paper";
string[] fields = input.split(new string[] { " " } , 
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

And then `field[2]` will contain what you want.